# VS Code SFTP почему открывает файлы в одной вкладке?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sftp

Установил дополнение SFTP в Visual Studio Code ( https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp ) настроил доступ к сайту по ftp, работает, но каждый раз при открытии файла он открывается в ранее открытой вкладке, вместо того чтобы открыться в новой. В чём причина где нужно поставить галку чтобы каждый открываемый файл открывался в новой вкладке?

Причём если изменить открытый файл (пробел поставить) то новый открываемый файл уже открывается как надо в новой вкладке.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я думаю этот вопрос стоит спросить у [разработчиков дополнения](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues)...

Comment: Они не поймут мой русский)

Comment: Пишите на английском)

Answer (score 0):

Все достаточно просто, в експлорере sftp нажимаешь правой мишкой и выбираешь Edit Local. После чего файл скачивается локально и ты можешь редактировать его, что бы редактировать несколько файлов в разных папках, **нужно кликать по файлу дважды**, тогда он будет открываться в новой вкладке.